# ActionBar Tab that contains fragments crashes when reshown

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an SherlockFragmentActivity that uses an ActionBar with tabs.  One of those tabs is an SherlockFragment that has a layout file that includes an fragment.  When that tab is first shown, all is great.  If I switch to another tab and then back to that tab, I get a crash:

`02-21 10:25:10.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3916): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #29: Duplicate id 0x7f06006e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.nexapps.myq.fragments.TitleInfo
02-21 10:25:10.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3916):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:275)
02-21 10:25:10.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3916):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
02-21 10:25:10.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3916):     ... 21 more`

My main activity:

```
public class TitleActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        ...
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ...
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.details);
        tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<TitleDetailsFragment>(this, "details", TitleDetailsFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);         
    }

}
```

Tab Listener:
public class TabListener implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
      private Fragment mFragment;
      private final Activity mActivity;
      private final String mTag;
      private final Class mClass;

```
  public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> cls) {
      mActivity = activity;
      mTag = tag;
      mClass = cls;
  }

  public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Fragment fragment) {
      mActivity = activity;
      mTag = tag;
      mClass = clz;
      mFragment = fragment;
  }

  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
      if (mFragment == null) {
          mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
          ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
      } else {
          ft.attach(mFragment);
      }

      TabChangeInterface tci = (TabChangeInterface) mActivity;
      if (tci != null) {
        tci.tabSelect(mTag);
      }
  }

  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
      if (mFragment != null) {
          ft.detach(mFragment);
      }
  }

  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  }
```

}

My Tab fragment:

```
public class TitleDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_title, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

R.layout.activity_title:

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/info"
   android:name="foo.TitleInfo"
   ...
```

I could remove the id (which fixes the issue) but those help with state changes.  Any thoughts on how to keep the ids and fix the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this has to do with the fact that tab contents are a fragment, and fragments can't contain fragments.  So use views instead here or manually remove/add using transactions.

Comment: This answer is actually not correct. The tabs are technically part of the actionbar. The fragments are completely separate, unless you are creating your own custom tabs by making a fragment tab. Also, you CAN embed fragments in fragments, but it sure makes things a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove fragments that are embedded in an xml layout. For that, you should change your xml to include a `<FrameLayout android:id="fragment_container" .../>` and then programmatically replace the fragments in the frame by calling:

```
MyFrag newFragment = new MyFrag();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,newFragment,"myFragName")
.addToBackStack("myFragName")//optional
.commit();
```

Assuming you are using support package, otherwise you just change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`

And you can read more about using fragments here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

EDIT: Updated to include code based on new information

R.layout.activity_title:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Title" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

TitleActivity.class:

```
public class TitleActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);        
         ...
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ...
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.details);
        tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<TitleDetailsFragment>(this, "details", TitleDetailsFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);         
    }

}
```

R.layout.details_fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Details are here!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TabFragment:

```
public class TitleDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

TabListener you can keep the same as your code above.

Comment: My code doesn't replace any fragments.  Unless you mean the base class is?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your issue. Since you have already compiled your code, if you now change `@+id` to `@id` it should work.

Comment: Then I get "resource not found" and it won't recompile.  It seems that onCreateView is being called when there already one still active with the same id

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to add the fragment when the fragment already exists, can you post the rest of your fragment code AND the activity code that is the parent of this fragment?

Comment: I added more info.  I am not adding anything in this case - I have a Activity that has tabs.  Tab 1 has TitleDetailsFragment in it, and TitleDetailsFragment has a layout file that contains a fragment (basically the fragment has a different layout file for landscape/portrait).  Whenever I first view the tab it works fine, but if I switch to another and back to it I get the exception.  So somehow the layout file with the fragment is being created and added again .

Comment: This seems to be related to a fragment containing a fragment

Comment: change your `ft.add`, `ft.attach` to `ft.replace` and remove the `ft.detach`--and refer to my answer about replacing fragments above--because this IS what you are doing--let me know how it goes Edit: Also, your fragment needs its own xml file, you did not put your activity xml, but judging by this `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_title, container, false);` in your fragment I bet you are inflating the same view twice, give me an hour and when I get home I'll post a full working example

Comment: So why would TitleActivity need an layout file?

Comment: Because the normal implementation is to use a "main" type of layout, then put fragments into it that you can quickly swap out, remove, add to etc.  For instance, your app is a very common use, you could have a `ListFragment` that has a bunch of songs in it, which is added to your activity, then when a user clicks on a song, you swap out the fragments and show the details (usually used on a phone-for a tablet its usually multi-pane). This also prevents you from trying to reinflate the same view and force close. Follow the link I provided in the answer for a better explanation